# Dynamically Added Event Handler Not Firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Here is a quick code snippet, that doesn't seem to work at all for me. I'm reading from a file to create a list of radio buttons. The problem is that when one of the radio buttons is clicked the Event Handler I have set up in the code doesn't fire. I have tested it over and over in debug mode with line breaks... all with no luck. Am I missing something obvious here????

```c#
     strLine = strLine.Trim();
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("[3-a] ship by date - date: " + strLine);
                    
     try{ shipByDate = (Convert.ToDateTime(strLine)); }
     catch (Exception e) { shipByDate = new DateTime(); }

     shipByDesc = sr.ReadLine().Trim();
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("[3-b] ship by date - desc: " + shipByDesc);

     RadioButton button = new RadioButton();
     button.Text = shipByDesc + " - " + shipByDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
     button.Checked = false;
     button.GroupName = "shipByOptions";
     button.ID = "shipByRadio" + count;
                    
     //button.EnableViewState = true;
     button.AutoPostBack = true;
     button.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(shipBy_CheckedChanged); // <-- doesn't work!!!

     //form1.Controls.Add(button);
     shipByPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(button);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the button on every postback before events attached to it will fire.

If you think about it for a moment, it will make sense - if the button has not been created (on the postback), then there are no button events that can fire. The button *must* exist before events attached to it can be fired.

The `OnInit` page event is the most suitable place to add dynamic controls to a page.

Read about the [asp.net page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

Comment: You rock Oded, thanks for the help. That was exactly the problem.

Comment: Got it, sorry I'm a bit new to SO. Check check check